# FindPOCO CMAKE script unable to find MYSQL::client

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using CMake to build a project that uses the PocoDataMySQL library.  I'm using the following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(sqltest VERSION 0.1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(Poco REQUIRED DataMySQL)
include_directories(${Poco_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

add_executable(sqltest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sqltest ${Poco_LIBRARIES})
```

When I try to configure the project using CMake, I get the following error message:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_executable):
[cmake]   Target "sqltest" links to target "MySQL::client" but the target was not
[cmake]   found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
[cmake]   an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Is there something I'm missing in my CMakeLists.txt file or is this a bug with the PocoConfig.cmake script provided by the Poco project?  I was able to build Poco itself without any issues.

When I run `mysql_config`, I get the following output:

```
Usage: /usr/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Compiler: GNU 9.3.0
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/usr/include/mysql ]
        --cxxflags       [-I/usr/include/mysql ]
        --include        [-I/usr/include/mysql]
        --libs           [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl]
        --libs_r         [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl]
        --plugindir      [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
        --socket         [/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [8.0.20]
        --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
                pkgincludedir [/usr/include/mysql]
                pkglibdir     [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
                plugindir     [/usr/lib/mysql/plugin]
```

Comment: Looks like Poko package file forget to call `find_dependecy` for MySQL. You may call `find_package(MySQL REQUIRED)` before line `find_package(Poco REQUIRED DataMySQL)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev , If I add that, I get another error about CMake not being able to find a package configuration file for MySQL.

Comment: Yes, you need to take [FindMySQL.cmake](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/master/cmake/FindMySQL.cmake) script from POCO, and add directory with this script to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by copying the `FindMySQL.cmake` file from the Poco source tree to `/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules` and including `find_package(MySQL REQUIRED)` before the `find_package(Poco REQUIRED DataMySQL)`.

I did submit this as an issue on the Poco GitHub page (https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/3028) because, according to their documentation, all you need is the line referencing Poco.